# Firebase Database add node to JSON tree for android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following structure in my Firebase Database JSON Tree:
[image]

Now I have the `requests` node as the following in Android:

`DatabaseReference requestsNode`

How can I add another node `request2` with all the information-childs (date, destination, origin, ...) to the `requests` node? At the time of execution I do not know how many requests are already in the tree. So I do not know the increment `request<number>` number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `push()` method to add new child instead of deciding the index for your child. It is based on timestamp so it will always unique and sorted chronologically.

So for your case

```
ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("requests");
ref.push().setValue(requestObject);
```

Hope this helps, comment if you have questions :)

Comment: How will the `requestObject` look like?

Comment: That's a POJO (Plain Old Java Object) containing "date", "destination", "origin", "status", and "time" as its properties. Read https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/save-data for more information @faraz_ahmed_kamran

Comment: OK, let me try. :)

Comment: Can you please tell me how I can retrieve all the `requests`child nodes?

Comment: @faraz_ahmed_kamran it's out of the topic haha. You can use `ValueEventListener` or `ChildEventListener`, more on this is in https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data . If you have a problem with that, create a new question for that :)